# Count documents for collections that name start with given strings

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo DB "db1" that have a collections like:

- Chocolate-31-Oct-2019
- Chocolate-30-Oct-2019
- Chocolate-29-Oct-2019
- Chocolate-28-Oct-2019
- Chocolate-27-Oct-2019
- Cookie-31-Oct-2019
- Cookie-30-Oct-2019
- Cookie-29-Oct-2019
- Cookie-28-Oct-2019
- Cookie-27-Oct-2019
- Cookie-26-Oct-2019
- Bar-31-Oct-2019
- Bar-30-Oct-2019
- Bar-29-Oct-2019
- Bar-28-Oct-2019
- Bar-27-Oct-2019

I want to count:

- number of collections for Chocolate and Cookie only
- number of documents for collections: Chocolate and Cookie only.

Using MongoChef shell console, I am able to count all documents per collection in a 'db' like this:

```
db.getCollectionNames()
.forEach(function(collection) 
{ resultCount = db[collection].count(); 
  print("Results count for " + collection + ": "+ resultCount);
  });
```

but don't know how to count for defined list of collections only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Updated with the number of collections count. Just copy-paste this into the console. 
    var chCount=0;
    var coCount=0;

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { 
if(collection.startsWith("Chocolate") || collection.startsWith("Cookie")){  
    if(collection.startsWith("Chocolate"))
        chCount=chCount+1;
    else if(collection.startsWith("Cookie"))
        coCount=coCount+1;
    resultCount = db[collection].count();    print("Results count for " + collection + ": "+ resultCount);   
}
});
print("Chocolate = "+chCount+", Cookie = "+coCount+".");
```

You may also write this into a .js file and execute using the following command.

```
mongo --port=<port> <database> <any authentication if required> ex.js
```

Comment: It works for second dot - number of documents for collections: Chocolate and Cookie only. Still need to count number of collections for Chocolate and Cookie only. Result should show: Chocolate = 5, Cookie = 6.